# Throughput values and Packet size in layer 2 forwading

Tags: throughput, dpdk

I have noted down a few values of throughput corresponding to different packet size in layer 2 forwarding. I have the following queries.

1. The MBits/s Rx/Tx : 87/1025 denotes that we have a throughput of 87 in the Rx queue and 1025 in the Tx queue right? So, if I am asked to find the throughput(in general) for a particular packet size how exactly should I be writing down the values? Initally, I noted the values by diving them. For instance 87/1025= 0.08MBits/s. I am not sure if this is a correct way.
2. The below are my observation of throughput for different packet size. As far as I know, as packet size increases throughput value decreases. In that case, I don't understand why throughput keeps increasing for Rx and Tx queue as the size increases.

   ```
     Packet_Size         Throughput 
        64                  11/201
        99                  19/283
        128                 26/333
        256                 39/659
        512                 112/1215
        1024                175/1304
   ```

It would be great if someone could give a clear idea on how to get the throughput values for packets of different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The MBits/s Rx/Tx : 87/1025 denotes that we have a throughput of 87 in the Rx queue and 1025 in the Tx queue right?

Right, this means packet generator sends 1025 Mbit/s of packets (Tx), but only 87 Mbit/s getting back (Rx).

> if I am asked to find the throughput(in general) for a particular packet size how exactly should I be writing down the values?

[Wikipedia says:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throughput)

> Network throughput is the rate of successful message delivery over a communication channel

So if we sent 1025 Mbit/s, but received back just 87 Mbit/s, those 87 Mbit/s is our throughput.

> As far as I know, as packet size increases throughput value decreases

That is true for throughput measured in packets per second: the bigger packet needs more time to send/receive it.

For throughput measured in bits per second it is quite the opposite. The formula is:

```
ThroughputBits = ThroughputInPPS * PacketSize * 8
```

So, while for bigger packets the `ThroughputInPPS` is getting lower, after we multiply it `PacketSize` times, the `ThroughputBits` still will be bigger. Unless we reach the line rate, but that is not your case.